# Simple question about proportions in a piece of artwork. Is the ratio $1.285$ significant?

Tags: geometry

I am trying to find some of the mathematics behind a page in the Book of Kells.

Basically, the likelihood of the scribes using random numbers is very unlikely for their proportions.  I mean, let's say you are building a house.  You don't make the window sizes 41.573 inches by 34.917.  Nope, you go with 42 inches and 30, or something nice and round.  When you are making a design using Autocad, the same principle applies.  For making this page of the Book of Kells page, 188r:

https://digitalcollections.tcd.ie/home/index.php?DRIS_ID=MS58_003v

they just had to use nice and round numbers for the framework. I am ignoring all the internal designs at this point in the project.

> After doing an analysis, I get 1.285 for the ratio of the rectangle that is surrounded by the half-circles.  Does that number have any significance?  It's too far away from 4/3rds, which is 1.333, which is about 3% off.

I mean, if you are measuring a window opening in a house and you get 40.002 and 31.999, obviously the builder was shooting for 40 by 32.

I did a screen-shot in Paint and then calculated the corners of the rectangle and came up with that 1.285.  Is it the square root of some nice round number?  Is it anything close to the golden ratio (it isn't).

It takes some playing around with, but there is bound to be some nice-round ratio that they used to make the rectangle.  It takes some playing-around with, because there are many edges to choose from.

Here's to hoping someone has some time on their hands and can figure out what the ratio of the framework of the design is.  Obviously they didn't use inches back then, but some other measuring tool.  Maybe some ratio that is easily made with a compass and ruler?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you can generate at least one more digit (hopefully more), you might consult the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html) to see if anything jumps out at you. (More digits are better. $1.2850$ gives almost 1800 results.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Obviously*, you want
$$\phi-\frac13 = 1.284700655\ldots$$
where $\phi := \frac12(\sqrt{5}+1)$ is the golden ratio. :)

Comment: Thanks man!  I thought it was a stupid question.  Much appreciated!  Thanks Fred too.  They didn't pull these numbers out of thin air after all.

Answer (score 2):

Your ratio, $1.285$, is quite close to the simple fraction $\dfrac97=1.285714\ldots$